# Some of my text contacts appear in red on Ipad/wont send

Tags: ios, ipad, messages

Have a new iPad Air.

When I try to send a text, some of the contacts come up in red instead of blue and I cannot send a text message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This happens when the person you are contacting is not registered with iMessage. Because your iPad is not connected to your phone policy (just data if anything), you are not able to text regular numbers. Your iPad is still a tablet, and so it cannot send regular SMS messages outside of iMessage, which is Apple's, not Verizon/AT&T/T-Mobile/Sprint's.